# localhost doesn't work inside my remote VS Code's webviews

Tags: node.js, subprocess, localhost, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I'm trying to implement the own VSCode extension. The extension will launch some subprocess that creates `localhost:port`. The website `localhost:port` should be loaded in `WebView`. At the moment it perfectly works on local machine but webview isn't loaded on remote machine when I use SSH connection.

As I know VSCode has some [problems](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/remote-extensions#using-the-webview-api) with using localhost from a webview. I have already tried to use the both described workarounds. But unfortunately no one works.

For example, I implemented second workraround from website. I create `panel` using the following code:

```
let panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(view_type, tab_name,
            vscode.ViewColumn.One,
            {
                enableScripts: true,
                retainContextWhenHidden: true
            });
```

Then I try to visualize localhost from subprocess:

```
const process = subprocess.spawn(cmd, [model_path]);
process.stdout.on('data', async (data) => {
            const output = data.toString();
            const url_path = output;
            const web_uri = await vscode.env.asExternalUri(vscode.Uri.parse(url_path));
            panel.webview.html = this.getHTMLForWebview(web_uri);
        });

private getHTMLForWebview(web_uri: vscode.Uri): string {
    return `
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Visualization</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <iframe
                width="100%"
                height="800" 
                src="${web_uri}"
            ></iframe>
        </body>
        </html>`;
}
```

As I said before it works on my local Windows machine. But I see empty webview (just an empty frame) on my remote Linux machine:
[image]

It's my first extension so probably I miss something.

What I should to add/rewrite to render localhost on remote machine?

Also I have already seen [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55978517/why-does-localhost-not-work-inside-my-vs-codes-webviews-when-connected-to-remot) solution. It's just a link to known website.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code is by default very restrictive what can be loaded. Add content security policies to enable more. Here's what I use to allow loading external resources:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; img-src http: https:;
    script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'unsafe-inline' http: https: data: *;">
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work on remote machine. Your comment is useful and needed too. Thanks for that! But seems like there is conflict between localhosts of VSCode and my subprocess.